# How to load list inside fragment?

Tags: java, android, list, android-fragments, fragment

I'm pretty new in android development. I have a slidemenu with the list options menu. When you click it loads the views, the fragments.  Here's my doubt, I want to load in the fragment one list.

I made ​​another app using volley and the lists works correctly but only have the lists. In slidemenu app I already import libs, strings and all. Now I don't know how to call the list here. The app structure: MainActivity calls fragments where each has its class, what should I do?

The code is on [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/SMweQkCt).

Comment: You should search for ListFragment

Comment: A minimal version of code that is sufficient to demonstrate the issue should be included in the question.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You should also read:  [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)